# Не понимаю, как расставить внешние ключи. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть у меня класс

```
public class Evaluation
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string InstructorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

и в таблицу нужны ключи. С БД пока дружу очень напряжённо, поэтому не проник ещё в таинства расстановки ключей.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Evaluation>().HasKey(e => new { e.StudentId, e.SubjectId, e.InstructorId });
```

В контексте пытаюсь сделать таким способом, но пишет, что эта дичь вызывает зацикливание или множественное каскадирование:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Evaluations_dbo.AspNetUsers_StudentId' on table 'Evaluations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   И сейчас я в непонятках, как поступить...

Comment: [ответ тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: Подробнее про связи между таблицами можно почитать тут [ссылка](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level2/2_2.php). Должно помочь!